# Adding Custom Fields to Woocommerce Custom Taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I've created a custom taxonomy called "vendors" in Woocommerce through this:

```
function vendor_taxonomy()  {
$labels = array(
    'name'                       => 'Vendors',
    'singular_name'              => 'Vendor',
    'menu_name'                  => 'Vendors',
    'all_items'                  => 'All Vendors',
    'parent_item'                => 'Parent Vendor',
    'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Vendor:',
    'new_item_name'              => 'New Vendor Name',
    'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Vendor',
    'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Vendor',
    'update_item'                => 'Update Vendor',
    'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Vendors with commas',
    'search_items'               => 'Search Vendors',
    'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove Vendors',
    'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used Vendors',
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => false,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 'item', 'product', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'vendor_taxonomy', 0 );
```

Now I would like to customize the fields in the admin page. Default fields are Name, Slug and Description. Let's say I would like to add an extra text fields called "featured products", I'm trying something like this below, but nothing happens in the admin page of the taxonomy:

```
add_action('vendors_add_form_fields', 'vendors_featured_wp_editor_add', 10, 1);

function vendors_featured_wp_editor_add() {
?>    
<div class="form-field">
    <label for="featured_products"><?php _e('Featured Products', 'wh'); ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="featured_products" id="featured_products">
    <p class="description"><?php _e('Enter 4 featured products, Comma separated', 
    'featured'); ?></p>
</div>
<?php
}
```

...

```
add_action('vendors_edit_form_fields', 'vendors_featured_wp_editor_edit', 10, 1);

function vendors_featured_wp_editor_edit($term) {

$term_id = $term->term_id;

$featured_products = get_term_meta($term_id, 'featured_products', true);
?>
<tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="featured_products"><?php _e('Featured 
    Products', 'featured'); ?></label></th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="featured_products" id="featured_products" value="<? 
        php echo esc_attr($featured_products) ? esc_attr($featured_products) : ''; ? 
        >">
        <p class="description"><?php _e('Enter 4 featured products, Comma separated', 
        'featured'); ?></p>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
```

...

```
add_action('edited_vendors', 'vendors_featured_save_wp_editor', 10, 1);
add_action('create_vendors', 'vendors_featured_save_wp_editor', 10, 1);

function vendors_featured_save_wp_editor($term_id) {

$featured_products = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'featured_products');

update_term_meta($term_id, 'featured_products', $featured_products);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You registered taxonomy with taxonomy key `item`:

`register_taxonomy( 'item', 'product', $args );`

Then you try to add hook to `vendors` taxonomy key:

`function vendors_featured_wp_editor_edit($term) {`

Check the name of your taxonomy.

Comment: Thanks indeed that was the issue